# SPSS Extension Command: Difference between Keywords and Subcommands?

Tags: python, dictionary, spss

For my extension command (for which I will create a CDB) I need the user to select  a dependent variable and independent variables. However, I am unsure what the command syntax for this would be. In some examples I see that 'VARIABLES' is a keyword for an anonymous subcommand, so how does this work when I have a dependent variable and independent variables? Are these subcommands or both just keywords for anonymous subcommands?

So for example, if the command name is 'MYCOMMAND', and 'income' is the dependent variable and 'gender' and 'education' are the independent variables... how would the syntax look like? If I give the dependent variable the identifier %%dep_var%%, and the independent variables the identifier %%indep_var%%, will the following work?

```
MYCOMMAND DEPENDENT=gender INDEPENDENT=income education
```

or

```
MYCOMMAND DEPENDENT=%%dep_var%% INDEPENDENT=%%indep_var%%
```

The XML would be:

```
<Command xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="extension.xsd"
Name="MYCOMMAND" Language="Python">
   <Subcommand Name="" Occurrence="Required" IsArbitrary="False">
      <Parameter Name="DEPENDENT" ParameterType="VariableName"/>
   </Subcommand>
   <Subcommand Name="" Occurrence="Required" IsArbitrary="False">
      <Parameter Name="INDEPENDENT" ParameterType="VariableNameList"/>
   </Subcommand>
</Command>
```

So that the 'args' fed to the run function would be the following dictionary;

```
{'MYCOMMAND': [{'': [{'DEPENDENT': 'gender'}]}, 
               {'': [{'INDEPENDENT': ['income', 'education']}]}]}
```

Or do I need to interpret it differently?